# PulP: Adding constraint which aggregates the variable

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I'm pretty new to python or rather coding in general and trying to find my way through. I spent days and nights on searching the web and read trough all tips and docs I've found in this regard but couldn't find the solution for my problem. 
My aim is actually a pretty basic LP, finding the most suitable amount of volume which is bound to a min and max per index lane and maximizing the profit which is different in each lane. I've found some code which base was pretty close to what I've been looking for and adjusted it according to my needs

```
prob = pulp.LpProblem('LaneSelectionOptimization', LpMaximize)

'''Set the variable'''
x = LpVariable.dicts('Lane',Lanes,None,None,LpInteger)


for l in Lanes:
 x[l].bounds(MinVols[l], MaxVols[l])


''' Set the objective function '''
prob += lpSum([x[l] * Impacts[l] for l in Lanes]), 'Sum_of_Impact'


''' Set the constraints '''
#to meet the requirements of the high level constrains i.e. total optimized volume shouldn't differ more than +/-10%
prob += lpSum([x[l] for l in Lanes]) <= VOLUME_LIMIT_UPPER
prob += lpSum([x[l] for l in Lanes]) >= VOLUME_LIMIT_LOWER
```

So far all went well and it does what it supposed to.

Now I tried to add another constraint which basically needs to aggregate the variable on a certain column string (SecToSecRel) i.e. creating a subtotal which should be less than the value which is allocated to the string in a different table

This is the part of the second table and the value which is aligned to it, which works.

```
Total_Customer_Target = pd.DataFrame({"TOrgNo":data2.iloc[:,1],"SecToSecRel":(data2.iloc[:,2]+data2.iloc[:,3]), "Target 2018":data2.iloc[:,6]})

SRGNRel_Customer_Target_lane = (Total_Customer_Target[Total_Customer_Target.SecToSecRel == SecToSecRel[l]].sum()["Target 2018"])*1.10
```

Then adding the constraint....I tried out various ways and unfortunately didn't keep all of them.

1st Try - Didn't work

```
prob += lpSum([x[l] for l in Lanes if any(SecToSecRel) == SecToSecRel[l]]) <= SRGNRel_Customer_Target_lane,
```

2nd Try - Stopped in the middle and returned a KeyError

```
for s in Total_Customer_Target.SecToSecRel:
    prob += lpSum([x[l] for l in Lanes if s in SecToSecRel[l]]) <= SRGNRel_Customer_Target_lane
```

3rd Try - Thought I had to get rid of the Key error to get it work, setting a default - but didn't work

```
for s in Total_Customer_Target.SecToSecRel:
    default = 'No Sector Relation'
    SecToSecRel.append(Total_Customer_Target.setdefault(s,default))
    prob += lpSum([x[l] for l in Lanes if s in SecToSecRel[l]]) <= SRGNRel_Customer_Target_lane,
```

Is there anyone who could help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like an interesting problem!

First of all, you can't use if statement when modeling your problem.

Just to be clear, you want the sum of lanes in SecToSecRel to be less than SRGNRel_Customer_Target_lane?

Comment: Thanks for coming back on this one and sorry for my late reply.

Comment: Yes, that's right! I don't want this particular subtotal to exceed the target, well it's rather a limitation. I thought I can filter the data set for each SRGNRel_Customer_Target_lane , take the lpSum and add it to the problem but I assume there are to many of them. Well I'm actually not sure. There are 169 of them running through 17000 lanes.